On-demand treatment or Required treament?
I'm struggling to name a department in my hospital in English.
This department provides paid treament services. I mean that we serve the needs of our patients.
Should I use "Department of On-demand Treatment" or "Department of Required Treatment"?

"we serve the needs of our patients"...doesn't every department in a hospital do that? "On-demand" suggests that patients are diagnosed and treated in the same session. "Required" suggests that you're treating them if treatment is required (and when would you treat them if they didn't required it?)

I mean our department serve paid services that are not cover by patients' national medical insurance. Eg. if a patient want to be cover by his insurance, he will be treated in other department in my hospital and my department only serves patients who want to pay money for their services.

To be more specific: I want to express that our services are voluntarily paid and not compulsory treatment. If a patient want it, we serve it and otherwise, they are free to go.

You could call it paid treatment. If you pay for it, it is your choice to demand it.

Most departments at hospitals are organized around a medical specialty.  Does your hospital focus exclusively on  a single specialty (e.g. maternity, oncology, opthalmology)? Or will this paid section address health issues across many specialties?  I'm wondering if "department" is the proper word.

Required care is covered care. Maybe Elective Treatment Centre.

@TimR our department focous mainly on internal medicine, not multiple specialties. So I think "department" is approriate. Thanks for your idea.

Special services?

In the UK, medical treatment that people choose to pay for rather than waiting their turn to be treated by the National Health Service is described as 'private', so you might call it the 'private wing/ward/section'.

this sounds suitable, I will consider this. Thanks very much!

Neither of your suggestions is appropriate.
"On Demand" means you get it when you ask for it. It does not tell you anything about whether it is paid for.
"Required" means the treatment is necessary. It doesn't mean paid for. I would bet that on average paid-for treatments are less necessary than others.
